# Invoke-RestMethod in Powershell only returning inner entry elements and not feed

Tags: rest, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am calling Powershell's `Invoke-RestMethod` on a feed with the following structure

```
<feed>
    <id>feed id</id>
    <author><name>John Smith</name></author>
    <title>Feed title</title>
    <updated>2017-03-17T12:57:28.898Z</updated>
    <link href="url A" rel="value A"/>
    <link href="url B" rel="value B"/>
    ... other elements ...
    <entry>
        <id>entry id</id>
        <author><name>John Smith</name></author>
        <title>Entry title</title>
        <updated>2017-03-17T12:57:28.898Z</updated>
        <link href="url C" rel="value C"/>
        <link href="url D" rel="value D"/>
        ... other elements ...
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I am using the following function

```
$xml = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Url -ContentType "application/atom+xml" -Credential $credentials
```

I get a successful response, but it only includes the `<entry>` element and not the `<feed>` element, and I need the values of the "url A" and "url B" links which are therefore not returned.

Normally I would say what I have tried at this point, but since I've found nothing on the internet, these are the only things I've tried.

1. Changing the request content type to "text/xml" - no change in the result.
2. Calling `$xml.ParentNode` and `$xml.OwnerDocument` in attempt to get the `<feed>` element, but it was not available.

How can I get the `<feed>` level elements?

My Powershell version is 5.1.14393.953

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke-RestMethod` only returns the entries in a rss or atom-feed, as stated on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod):

> Windows PowerShell formats the response based to the data type. For an
>   RSS or ATOM feed, Windows PowerShell returns the Item or Entry XML
>   nodes. For JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) or XML, Windows
>   PowerShell converts (or deserializes) the content into objects.

You can use `Invoke-WebRequest` to read the original xml and access the feed-element. Ex.

```
$xml = [xml](Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Credential $credentials)
```

Sample output:

```
PS> $xml.feed   

xmlns   : http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
title   : VG ATOM Feed
link    : {link, link}
id      : http://www.vg.no/rss/feed/forsiden/?format=atom
updated : 2017-03-19T18:36:56+01:00
entry   : {entry, entry, entry, entry...}
```

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` got me the whole feed (i.e. solved the question). I misread the MSDN information before - thanks for pointing out what it actually meant.